# Prove $\forall n\ge 2, 2^{n}-1 \nmid \ 3^{n}-1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

How can I prove for $n\ge 2$ that
$$ 2^{n}-1 \nmid \ 3^{n}-1$$
I have not been able to make any progress on this whatsoever. I would appreciate if someone can give me a hint!

Comment: FYI: The TeX-command `\nmid` gives $\nmid$ which is designed to look good as the symbol meaning lack of divisibility :-)

Comment: An easy observation is that for even $ n \geq 2 $, $ 2^n - 1 $ is divisible by $ 3 $ but $ 3^n - 1 $ is not, so the claim is true for even $ n \geq 2 $.

Comment: @MartinSleziak: I put the [tag:number-theory] tag back in there, because the only correct answer needs quadratic reciprocity. The tag descriptions seem to imply that quadratic reciprocity raises the question above our usual elementary-number-theory. I'm not sure that reciprocity is enough, because my rule of thumb is that *if I know it, it is elementary number theory*. What do you think?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen [Retagging based on answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/2612) is certainly common practice and that's perfectly ok. The only question is under which tag quadratic reciprocity belongs. Your edit is certainly in accordance with [the current tag-info](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/22236/revisions). There was a [suggestion on meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19092/how-to-differentiate-between-elementary-number-theory-and-number-theory/19224#19224) that this topic belongs to elementary-number-theory tag, but no consensus was reached.

Comment: I added my upvote to your tagging proposal @Martin, if it weren't for the weight of history (of tagging practice on our site) I think we should adopt that suggestion. Continue the discussion there, if the need arises. Not a hugely pressing concern.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $n$ is even, consider modulo $3$.

Assume $n$ is odd, and assume for contradiction that the division holds. If $p=4k+3$ is a prime divisor of $2^n-1$, then it is also a prime divisor of $3^n-1$. Using this and quadratic reciprocity, can you show that $p=3l+2$ for some integer $l$? Similarly, if $p=4k+1$, show that $p=3l+1$ for some $l$.

This means the prime divisors $\equiv 3\pmod 4$ of $2^n-1$ are exactly those $\equiv 2\pmod 3$. Since $2^n-1\equiv 3\pmod 4$, there should be an odd number of them (counting multiplicities), which means they multiply to $2\pmod 3$. This means $2^n-1\equiv 2\pmod 3$ as well, a contradiction.

Comment: The only correct argument out of 4 answers, remarkably...

Comment: In case I am not the only user who had to pause at a certain point: *If $n$ is odd, and $p\mid 3^n-1$, then $3$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$.* Then apply reciprocity. (+1, of course)

Comment: pi66, sorry to come back so late. When I composed my own answer and remarked on your proof, I thought I'd understood or would be able to understand later. However this did not happen. Now I think I might be able to relate this question to the detail of the "1-cycles" (R. Steiner, J. Simons) in the Collatz-problem  and so it would be important for me to understand your proof on my own. Would you mind to elaborate on your proof a bit more - I looked at the modulus-conditions of the primefactors but I'm illiterate with quadratic reciprocity... (Or should ask a new question instead?)

Comment: @GottfriedHelms You can read about quadratic reciprocity [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity). With that (and Jyrki Lahtonen's comment), my answer should be pretty clear. But if you still have some specific questions, feel free to ask me in a comment!

Comment: Pi66 - thanks! The wikipedia-entry is much enhanced compared to some older visits years ago; perhaps I manage to get that concept operable for me next days trying with exercises. If I'll still need help, I'll ask, but surely only after some days...

Answer (score 2):

*(This is more a comment than an answer)*

I'd like to relate the problem to a well known (but unsolved) conjecture, from where the question would immediately be answered - from a consequence of the famous Waring-problem (see for instance mathworld, "[power fractional parts](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PowerFractionalParts.html)").
 We rearrange the given expression and adapt it to the similar expression which occurs in the Waring-problem:
$$\Large \begin{array}{} {3^n-1 \over 2^n-1} &= {3^n \over 2^n-1}-{1 \over 2^n-1} \\
 &= {3^n \over 2^n}+{3^n \over 4^n}+{3^n \over 4^n}\left({1 \over 2^n}+{1 \over 4^n}...\right)-1\left({1 \over 2^n}+{1 \over 4^n}...\right) \\
&={3^n \over 2^n}+{3^n \over 4^n} - \left(1-{3^n \over 4^n}\right){1 \over 2^n-1} \\
{3^n-1 \over 2^n-1} & \lt {3^n \over 2^n}+{3^n \over 4^n} \end{array}
$$
The comparision on the rhs of the "$\lt$" reflects a detail of the Waring-problem: there we have the conjecture (for $n \gt 6$), that 
$$ \Large \begin{array}{}
  & \Big \lfloor {3^n \over 2^n} \Big \rfloor & \lt &{3^n \over 2^n}-{3^n \over 4^n} & \qquad \small ( \text{ and of course } \lt{3^n \over 2^n} )\\
\small \text{and} &&& {3^n \over 2^n}+{3^n \over 4^n} &\lt \Big \lceil {3^n \over 2^n} \Big \rceil \end{array}$$
So, if the Waring-conjecture holds, we have that $  {3^n-1 \over 2^n-1} $ is smaller than the next greater integer above   $  {3^n \over 2^n} $ so we get immediately that $2^n-1 $ does never evenly divide $3^n-1$ when $n \gt 6$  .

I find this a nice and challenging conjecture.
Unfortunately the nice proof of @pi66 does not in reverse help for the truth of the Waring-conjecture...