# Prove that $2^{n}-1\nmid3^{n}-1$ for all odd integers $n\geq3$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

> Prove that $2^{n}-1\nmid3^{n}-1$ for all odd integers $n\geq3$.

After factoring the numbers for some small $n$'s, I guess $\gcd(2^n-1,3^n-1)=1$ for all odd integers $n\geq3$, but I am unable to prove this. I tried infinite descent but to no avail. It seems to have something to do with Mersenne primes. Any hints will be appreciated.

Comment: I doubt that $gcd(2^n-1,3^n-1)=1$ when $n=(p-1)/2$ for some prime $p=4K-1$.

Comment: Ok, counter example for that: $p=47,n=23$.

Comment: @QuangHoang Thanks for your counterexample! But how do we solve this problem then?

Comment: Also [Prove $\forall n\ge 2, 2^{n}-1 \nmid \ 3^{n}-1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1903086/prove-forall-n-ge-2-2n-1-nmid-3n-1)